# Plotting different color lines based on a column

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I'm currently working with a dataframe that looks like this (it has 24 hours, here I show 2 hours):

[image: Dataframe]

The image just shows the first 5 rows, but there ar 4 different clusters and 3 different classes. The clusters were assigned regardless of the class, so any cluster may contain rows belonging to all 3 classes.

What I would need to do is make as many line graphs as clusters I have, where I can show the cluster's centroid as well as all rows belonging to that cluster. However, what I need — and cannot seem to find a way to do it — is to graph the line belonging to each class within a cluster in a different color. This means each graph would have at most 4 different colors, 1 for the centroid and 1 for each class.

Here is the code I'm currently using to graph the cluster centroid as well as the lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import seaborn as sb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
from tslearn.clustering import TimeSeriesKMeans
from tslearn.datasets import CachedDatasets
from tslearn.preprocessing import TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance

%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 9)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
K = 4

X = np.array(dffinal[['h0','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9','h10','h11','h12','h13','h14','h15','h16','h17','h18','h19','h20','h21','h22','h23']])
y = np.array(dffinal.index)
euc_km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=K,
                           metric='euclidean')
cluster = euc_km.fit_predict(X)
dffinal['cluster'] = cluster

for name, data in dffinal.groupby('cluster'):
    for xx in X[cluster == name]:
        plt.plot(euc_km.cluster_centers_[name].ravel(), "r-")
        plt.plot(xx.ravel(), "k-", alpha=.2)
    #plt.xlabel('Hour')
    #plt.ylabel('Demand')
    #plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('plot_euc_{}.png'.format(name))
    plt.close()
```

These are the kind of graphs obtained with the current code:

[image: Centroid in Red, All lines in Black]

I have been trying to include a second condition after the first `groupby` during the graph coding, but I can't seem to pull it off.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I believe i got it to work by using the following code, in case anyone else also faced the same issue.

```
    s = ['deepskyblue','darkorange','magenta']
for name, data in dffinal.groupby('cluster'):
    counter = -1
    for categoria, data in dffinal.groupby('clase'):
        counter = counter + 1
        for curve in Xc[(clase == categoria) & (cluster == name)]:
            plt.plot(curve.ravel(), s[counter], alpha=0.1)
    plt.plot(euc_km.cluster_centers_[name].ravel(), "r-")
    plt.savefig('plot_euc_{}.png'.format(name))
    plt.close()
```

Here is how my final graph looks. I have over 1450 rows of data where around 1250 belong to the same class, thats why most are cyan but you can still see some orange and magenta somewhere in there. The red one is still the cluster centroid. Hope it helps anyone doing something similar.
[image]